# Faster way to Extract HOG of image's sliding window in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I want to extract the HOG of every sliding window of size [wH,wW] of an image I.

Currently what I have is:

---

```
windows = im2col(I, [wH,wW]);

for i=1:step:size(windows,2)

    sub = reshape(windows(:,i), [wH,wW]);

    features(i,:) = featuresExtraction(sub);

end
```

---

in which the featuresExtraction script will extract the HOG, etc.

I try to run and see that it runs very very slowly. Do you have any suggestion to make it better?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest that you profile your code with the Matlab profiler.

When you have done this I think you will see that the either the function `featuresExtraction` or `im2col` is the reason for your slow computation. `im2col` is a function that also calls other Matlab functions. You can see that when you mark the function name and check with a right click on "Open Selection" if there is a lot of Matlab code within the newly opened file.

The `for` loop seems to be correct but of course, your code iterates over every possible window in the image and that is very slow, especially in Matlab loops are very slow.

When you really want to speed up your code I propose that you implement the computational expensive methods in C with a MEX interface. For a good tutorial check this out: [A Short MEX Tutorial and Demo](http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/03/getting-started-with-mex-a-short-tutorial/)

Comment: Actually it's the 'for' loop that makes things slow. I would prefer to have a matlab solution to this, rather than writing another C file (I am not very familiar with C). And also, in the 'featureExtraction' function, I also call functions from other libs as well. So I'm not sure how to write a C code to achieve that..

Comment: Can you tell me how large your images are and how complex the `featuresExtraction` method is? I think that `featuresExtraction` is implemented to compute the features of **exactly one** small window. As an example, if `featuresExtraction` does not support a input matrix of size `[wH, wW, size(windows,2)]` or some other input format which can prevent this `for` loop you will have to live with this speed.